# Wordpress wesbsite high loading time

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site that takes up to 10 seconds to load.
Even the editing page /wp-admin takes a long time to load.
I pinged the webpage using cmd and ping takes about 170ms.
I analyzed the webpage using https://www.isitwp.com and it states the server response time is 2.4 seconds(once it reported 4.6 seconds). 
Checked the network tab on Mozilla Firefox and this was the result for the loading of the HTML page:
[image]

Any suggestions on what could be the cause? Do you think the issue is on hosting end or optimization of the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

1. deactivate all plugins and check load time
2. reactivate plugins one by one and check which plugin is causing the issue
3. check theme response time
4. check server response time
5. wordpress works better with linux web hosting
   6.you are advised to use custom theme from scratch for maintaining a good speed

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your server takes a long time to process the php code on your installation.

If you can't get rid of any plugins that cause that issue, try [this guide](https://gtmetrix.com/wordpress-optimization-guide.html). These methods helped me to reduce my load times from ~ 7 sec to ~ 1 sec.